# How to lock mouse cursor to the middle of the screen? (18.04)

Tags: scripts, shortcut-keys, mouse, games, steam

So, I'm quiet new to ubuntu/linux and not quite good at the coding part but basically what I want to do is to write a code that keeps the cursor in the middle of the screen, but still movable. (Just like in games with crosshairs, you can see how cursor is stuck in the middle when you make it visible. It still tries to move but snaps back into same point and looks like It's flickering). And then make it toggle-able so that I can bind it to a key and toggle it on or off whenever I want. I also want it to be usable while there is a fullscreen application infront.

Reason for that is, I'm using Steam's Proton to play few games, and there are still few issues about that. When you alt-tab and back to the game (no matter what the window mode is), you can't look around properly because on the background mouse is hitting the screen borders so you can't look right or left anymore. Nobody seems to understand why this happens currently but a lot of people have encountered with this issue. And this is what I thought of. It won't solve the issue obviously, but can be workaround.

Is it possible to write a macro or program like this and work on the background all the time and toggle on and off at will?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98152/discussion-on-question-by-kiltenth-how-to-lock-mouse-cursor-to-the-middle-of-the).

Answer (score 0):

Try `watch -n0 xdotool mousemove x y`, note that you'll have to install `xdotool` using `sudo apt-get install -y xdotool` ([man xdotool](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html)).

Your terminal output should like the following, with the added drawback that you have to tab out and `ctrl+c` to kill it if you need to release the mouse. Happy gaming!

> `Every 5.0s: xdotool mousemove 683 380`